# php result did not show up using ajax for android (phonegap)

Tags: php, javascript, android, ajax, cordova

I am making an application for android using phonegap.

When I am using a browser, everything works perfectly.

But when I am using an emulator, devices (gingerbread and ice-cream sandwich) the result does not show up and nothing happens when I click the button.

Here is my code:

**index.html**

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/klass.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBMxwZns469iKK_rZiu7m1Z-xD4Qv8jKf0&sensor=true"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.map.full.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.map.extensions.js"></script> 
<script src="js/code.photoswipe-3.0.4.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

<div id="find_hotel" data-role="page">
<div data-role="header">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">Back</a> 
    <h3>HOTEL</h3>
</div>
<div data-role="content" id="cat_hotel">
    <a href="#" data-role="button">All</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button">Star 1</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button">Star 2</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button">Star 3</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button">Star 4</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button">Star 5</a>
</div>
</div>

<div id="hasilhotel" data-role="page">
</div>
```

**script.js**

```
$('#find_hotel').live('pageshow',function(){
$('#cat_hotel').bind('click',function(e){
    var id_subkategori, id_kategori;
    id_kategori=2;
    switch ($(e.target).children().html()) { 
    case 'All': 
        //alert('all');
        id_sub_kategori='';
        break;  
    case 'Star 1': 
       id_sub_kategori=3;
        break; 
    case 'Star 2': 
       id_sub_kategori=4;
        break;  
    case 'Star 3': 
       id_sub_kategori=5;
        break; 
    case 'Star 4': 
       id_sub_kategori=6;
        break; 
    case 'Star 5': 
       id_sub_kategori=7;
        break;      
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                var latitude=position.coords.latitude;
                var longtitude=position.coords.longitude;
                var postdata = {'id_sub_kategori':id_sub_kategori,'id_kategori':id_kategori,'latitude':latitude,'longtitude':longtitude};
                var output = $('#hasilhotel');
                var link = 'http://172.19.200.114/TA/php/find.php';
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: link,
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    data: postdata,
                    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
                    timeout: 5000,
                    success: function(data){
                        var str='the layout in html';
                        var count=0;
                        $.each(data, function(i,item){
                            str = str +'<li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c"><a href="#"><h3 class="ui-li-heading"><input type="hidden" value="'+item["id_place"]+'" id="id_place" >'+item["nama_place"]+'     &emsp; :     ('+item["distance"]+' Km)</h3></a></li>';
                            count++;
                        });
                        if(count==0)
                        {
                            str = str +'<li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">Tidak ada Tempat Terdekat</h3></li>';
                        }
                        str=str+'</ul></div>';
                        output.html(str);
                        $.mobile.changePage('#hasilhotel');
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert('There is a problem 6',null,'Error','Ok');
                    }
                });
            });
    });
});
```

**find.php**

```
include 'db.php';

$longtitude = $_POST["longtitude"];
$latitude = $_POST["latitude"];
$id_sub_kategori=$_POST["id_sub_kategori"];
$id_kategori=$_POST["id_kategori"];

$hasil = mysql_query ("
    select a.*,( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(".$latitude.") ) * cos( radians( a.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( a.longtitude ) - radians(".$longtitude.") ) + sin( radians(".$latitude.") ) * sin( radians( a.latitude ) ) ) ) as distance
    from place a inner join sub_kategori b on a.id_sub_kategori=b.id_sub_kategori
    where a.id_sub_kategori like '%".$id_sub_kategori."%' and b.id_kategori like '%".$id_kategori."%' and
    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(".$latitude.") ) * cos( radians( a.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( a.longtitude ) - radians(".$longtitude.") ) + sin( radians(".$latitude.") ) * sin( radians( a.latitude ) ) ) ) < 10");

$arr=array();

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
{
    $arr[]=array("id_place"=>$row['id_place'],"nama_place"=>$row['nama_place'],"alamat"=>$row['alamat'],"no_telp"=>$row['no_telp'],
    "longtitude"=>$row['longtitude'],"latitude"=>$row['latitude'],"deskripsi"=>$row['deskripsi'],"distance"=>number_format($row['distance'], 2, '.', ''));
}

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($arr) . ');';
```

Anyone any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Is your fail alert triggered?

Comment: Nothing happens when you click the button? Can you post more of your index.html code so we can see if the Cordova javascript is set up correctly? It sounds like maybe you're not waiting for `deviceReady` to be fired? You don't get anything in the logs?

Comment: @gameower : no alert.just nothing happen after i click the button.

Comment: @MBillau this is the index.html 


<div id="find_hotel" data-role="page">
 <div data-role="header">
  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="back">Back</a> 
  <h3>HOTEL</h3>
 </div>
 <div data-role="content" id="cat_hotel">
  <a href="#" data-role="button">All</a>
  <a href="#" data-role="button">Star 1</a>
  <a href="#" data-role="button">Star 2</a>
  <a href="#" data-role="button">Star 3</a>
  <a href="#" data-role="button">Star 4</a>
  <a href="#" data-role="button">Star 5</a>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="hasilhotel" data-role="page">
</div>

Comment: Are you including cordova.js somewhere? Wrapping your code in deviceReady function?

Comment: @MBillau yeah..of course...i put it at the same directory with index.html

Comment: Can you just please edit your question and post the entire HTML code? It sounds like Cordova is not being initialized, so I'm thinking there might be a conflict with your `<script type="text/javascript" src=cordova|jquery|jqm></script>` lines. For example, I've heard cordova.js needs to be included first because of collisions with `require`.

Comment: @MBillau just put the initialized of the files in html

Comment: Try putting your cordova.js script first. Then add this to the top of your script and see if you get the console.log() message: `document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    console.log("device ready!");
}, false);`
It should say 'device ready' in your console. You'll have to test in an emulator or device and look in the logcat.

Comment: where i put this one? console.log()
cordova or script.js?

Comment: Try putting that function/line in the first line of script.js. Then when you fire up the app you should see the message `device ready!` in the console.

Comment: @MBillau ok..i will try...i will report the result again :)

Comment: @MBillau oh ok...now i got "device ready" in my logcat

Comment: @MBillau now im trying to run this application on my devices, in logcat i got this error.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < at http://*my ip address*/TA/php/find.php?jsoncallback=jQuery16405821511950343847_1369403394024&id_sub_kategori=&id_kategori=2&latitude=-7.3427597&longtitude=112.7367569&_=1369403482221:1

Comment: Try to change your `success` function to just output the returned JSON from your PHP script to determine if the syntax error happens when you create the HTML strings or somewhere else. If you can get the JSON back and print it to the console, then you know the problem is in your string concatenation code.

Comment: so, what should i write in the success function?
sorry..im still new in this programming..
am i must write   $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($arr) . ');';  ??

Comment: Change your success function to just `console.log(data)` which will print out the data you get back from your PHP to logcat.

Comment: @MBillau this is the logcat..
http://*my ip address*/TA/php/find.php?jsoncallback=jQuery16404976035424042493_1369408252230&id_sub_kategori=&id_kategori=2&latitude=-7.3427597&longtitude=112.7367569&_=1369408269585: Line 1 : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: I'm not sure why there is an error...Do you have a 'jsoncallback' function defined in your javascript somewhere, which would be needed since you are using JSONP? Does the "Line 1: Uncaught SyntaxError" appear on a different line in logcat, indicating that at least you get the data back?  I'm running out of ideas...

Comment: @MBillau so do i...confuse...
of course it has jsoncallback etc..
hmm...how to check if the longitude and latitude successfully sent to the php?

Comment: I think you are confused about the JSONP thing. First, I don't think that `$_GET['jsoncallback']` will return anything, because it doesn't look like you are passing `jsoncallback` parameter to your PHP anywhere - try changing it to `$_GET['jsonp']` which is the name of the attribute you are sending in your AJAX request. Then, in your success function, you wont be able to get the JSON variables like you expect because your PHP is actually returning the string: `jsoncallback(...your data...)` and not a JSON object. To answer your question the only way I can think of is to check your PHP log...

Comment: after i read carefully, there is 1 parameter is added.and i dont know what is that....
at http://*my ip address*/TA/php/find.php?jsoncallback=jQuery16405821511950343847_1369403394024&i‌​d_sub_kategori=&id_kategori=2&latitude=-7.3427597&longtitude=112.7367569&_=136940‌​3482221
id_subkategori, id_kategori, latitude, longtitude, and what is the last one..hmmm